# R format number syntax

Tags: r, percentage

I'm trying to display some numbers as percentages.

```
data <- read.csv(
"http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data", 
    header = FALSE, 
    na.strings = "?", 
strip.white = TRUE
)
colnames(data) <- c("age", "workclass", "fnlwgt", "education", "education-num", "marital-status", "occupation", "relationship", "race", "sex", "capital-gain", "capital-loss", "hours-per-week", "native-country", "prediction")

colSums(is.na(data))/nrow(data)*100
```

The last command there outputs

```
       age      workclass         fnlwgt      education  education-num marital-status     occupation   relationship 
  0.000000       5.638647       0.000000       0.000000       0.000000       0.000000       5.660146       0.000000 
      race            sex   capital-gain   capital-loss hours-per-week native-country     prediction 
  0.000000       0.000000       0.000000       0.000000       0.000000       1.790486       0.000000
```

It seems like it would be hard to format those, but honestly I'm still thinking R works via black magic so is there some black magic that can format those the same way `sprintf("%.1f %%", 100*somePercentage)` formats `somePercentage`?

Hoped for output:

```
age      workclass         fnlwgt      education
  0.0%       5.63%         0.0%          0.0%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
v2 <- as.numeric(substr(v1, 1,4))
v1[] <- ifelse(v2==0, sprintf('%.1f%%', v2), sprintf('%.2f%%', v2))
v1
#          age      workclass         fnlwgt      education  education-num 
#      "0.0%"        "5.63%"         "0.0%"         "0.0%"         "0.0%" 
# marital-status     occupation   relationship           race            sex 
#     "0.0%"        "5.66%"         "0.0%"         "0.0%"         "0.0%" 
#  capital-gain   capital-loss hours-per-week native-country     prediction 
#   "0.0%"         "0.0%"         "0.0%"        "1.79%"         "0.0%"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- colSums(is.na(data))/nrow(data)*100
```

Comment: This works, but I'm not clear on why `v1[] <- stuff` works. I understand that v1 is a data frame, that has col headers, and that's why it prints as it does. It seems the `ifelse` pretends it's in a `map` call, along with every other function in this damn language, so it just returns a data frame with no col headers? So if you just say `df[] <- otherDf` will it just replace the data of `df` with the data of `otherDf`?

Comment: @Scuzzball `v1` is a vector with `name` attributes.  You could check the `str(v1)`, `is.vector(v1)`.  The `ifelse` works in the normal manner.  I used `v1[]` so that the attributes of v1 are retained in the output.  If you look at the output of `ifelse` or `v2`, it doesn't have the name attributes.  Regarding the `df[] <-  otherdf`, it will replace the data of `df` if the dimensions are the same.